# Create a list of random reals

Tags: list-manipulation, random

How can I create a list of random pairs $(x,y)$ where $0<y<x<1$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ ? I can't seem to place that inequality restriction on the random numbers that are generated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
RandomReal[1, {100, 2}] /. {x_, y_} /; y > x :> {y, x}
```

The graphics below confirm that you retain a uniform distribution

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Generate random pairs, and reverse-sort each one:

```
Sort[#, Greater] & /@ RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]
```

or, for fun, generate two numbers between 0 and 0.5, and add the second to the first:

```
RandomReal[0.5, {10, 2}].{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}
```

Comment: I don't believe the second method is valid: the smaller value can never exceed 0.5, incorrectly ruling out e.g. `{0.8, 0.7}`.

Comment: **Note:** While the second method has problems the first is correct, and it is **four times faster** than RunnyKine's (admittedly pretty) method.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is

```
{#, RandomReal[#]} & /@   RandomVariate[TriangularDistribution[{0, 1}, 1], 1000]
```

To see we do have a uniform distribution:

```
PDF[
    TransformedDistribution[{x, y}, {
                x  TriangularDistribution[{0, 1}, 1],
                y  UniformDistribution[{0, b}]
                }] /. b -> x,
    {x, y}]
```

[image: uniform distribution on 0<y<x<1]

Comment: It looks like [that is NOT an uniform distribution](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8mTuN.png).

Comment: @Silvia yes it is not uniformly distributed

Comment: Maybe something like `{#, RandomReal[#]} & /@ 
 RandomVariate[TriangularDistribution[{0, 1}, 1], 100000]`?

Comment: @Silvia Very good.  Either edit this Answer to include that or post your own.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard done :)

Comment: @Silvia great idea. thanks for adding it to the answer.